# Sent transaction from exchange to ICO (transaction failed)

Tags: transactions, wallets, exchanges

I sent [a transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe06e113b7fdfeac9fee68aed3341d95e7f2ab947f2e0d5bab5826020ae699aaa) from an exchange to an ICO and my transaction failed. Is there any way to retrieve my Eth from the ICO smart contract address? I guess somehow my transaction failed. please help if you can.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the transaction hash? We can't really tell you anything without providing one of those. E.g., 0x5876122bc859e97527741d20e084918d06285f22f13c0b844b7b60b9e7fd7914 is a TxHash.

Comment: If I give you my transaction hash wont you be able to access my account and take my funds??

Comment: No, a TxHash is a unique representation of the contract on the ethereum network. It allows people to audit and view what happened with the transaction.

Comment: 0xe06e113b7fdfeac9fee68aed3341d95e7f2ab947f2e0d5bab5826020ae699aaa

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Etherscan results of the transaction hash you posted](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe06e113b7fdfeac9fee68aed3341d95e7f2ab947f2e0d5bab5826020ae699aaa), the transaction did indeed fail.

[image: failed tx]

This means that all of the ether that you sent from the address [0x2d5bda26c47acdc5ca1388a9a6fd749b3a7ee984](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2d5bda26c47acdc5ca1388a9a6fd749b3a7ee984)
 are back at that address.

You initially said that this was from an exchange, but I doubt it. You probably control this address somehow or somewhere. Most exchanges use a hot wallet that has a huge number of transactions per day and a large amount of Ether stored. This wallet has only a couple transactions, a fund for approximately 0.64 ether, and then a subsequently failed transaction.

Assuming that you have the wallet for this address, the only money you lost was the transaction fee. The rest of the money is still on the wallet.

If it was indeed an exchange held address (just an oddly small one), then contacting the exchange should get your funds returned to you. This is because they can see the history on your account with withdrawal requests, and the address they used to fund the transaction. You should be able to get it back, as long as either you hold the wallet or the exchange is ethical and has logs.

Comment: Thank you ! I have already contacted exchange support. I appreciate your help. I feel a little bit better . I will take your advice and learn how to  create a wallet that i can run on my computer. Thanks again!! You are awesome!!!!

Comment: It's a peculiar address. You need to definitely contact the exchange, because it looks like a normal wallet address to me (e.g., one you might control). Either way, that's your support situation -- a failed transaction just means the sending address gets refunded.

Comment: Thanks again i feel soo much better knowing this!!

Comment: Good luck! Ask another question if you need more help, and don't forget to mark the answers on StackExchange as "accepted" if you they answer your question.